# Android Archive (AAR) package obfuscation

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation, aar

I'm setting obfuscation rules for a library project (AAR file). All the rules are respected. However, all the package names aren't obfuscated. The default behavior for the obfuscation is that all package names are obfuscated, **are there any special rules to obfuscate package names?**

Comment: If you are going to be sharing the AAR file with other projects - how will they link to your API if the package name is obfuscated?

Comment: I need all the packages that have no shared files to get obfuscated. For example, i have an encryption package that's not for use outside of the AAR itself. I need to obfuscate the package name for this package.