# Android Proguard unable to obfuscate libaary aar package name

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to  Obfuscate using proguard ,

**I use some library Projects and aar libs. For both of these the pacakge name is visible. I need to obfuscate the package name.**

**Proguard**

```
    # This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}


-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn microsoft.aspnet.signalr.**

-dontwarn  okio.**
-dontnote  okio.**

-dontnote com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

-dontwarn  android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontnote retrofit2.**
-dontnote okhttp3.**
-dontnote android.net.http.**
```

**Build.gradle**

```
 debug {


            shrinkResources false

            debuggable true

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
```

I have referred to :

[Android Archive (AAR) package obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356498/android-archive-aar-package-obfuscation)

[Android Archive (AAR) package obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356498/android-archive-aar-package-obfuscation)

[How to obfuscate android library(.aar) using proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236208/how-to-obfuscate-android-library-aar-using-proguard)

Thanks